# check if two lists of objects have the same value of an attribute

Tags: java, stream

I have two lists of objects
**localList** and **remoteList**, both lists have a **consent** attribute

I want to check the value of the consent attribute if the same for both lists.

If not, I want to remove all objects from localList that don't have  the same consent value as in remoteList and add all objects that have a consent value that exists in remoteList and not in localList

I implemented this solution but I want to improve it

Java Example

```
class Customer{

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer consent;

    public Customer(Long id, String name, Integer consent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.consent = consent;
    }

    public Integer getConsent() {
        return consent;
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    public java.lang.String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", consent=" + consent +
                '}';
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Customer> localList = new ArrayList<>();
    localList.add(new Customer(1L, "name1", 12));
    localList.add(new Customer(2L, "name2", 13));
    localList.add(new Customer(3L, "name3", 14));
    localList.add(new Customer(4L, "name4", 15));

    List<Customer> remoteList = new ArrayList<>();
    remoteList.add(new Customer(10L, "name1", 12));
    remoteList.add(new Customer(11L, "name2", 11));
    remoteList.add(new Customer(12L, "name3", 14));
    remoteList.add(new Customer(13L, "name4", 16));

    Map<Integer, Customer> map = remoteList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getConsent() , s -> s));
    Map<Integer, Customer> map2 = localList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getConsent() , s -> s));

      List<Customer> remove = new ArrayList<>();

    localList.forEach(e -> {
        if(map.get(e.getConsent()) == null ) {
            remoteList.add(e);
        }
    });

    remoteList.forEach(e -> {
        if(map2.get(e.getConsent()) == null ) {
            remove.add(e);
        }
    });

    remove.forEach(e ->  remoteList.remove(e));

    remoteList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

the remoteList

```
Customer{id=10, name='name1', consent=12}
Customer{id=11, name='name2', consent=11}
Customer{id=12, name='name3', consent=14}
Customer{id=13, name='name4', consent=16}
```

the localList

```
Customer{id=1, name='name1', consent=12}
Customer{id=2, name='name2', consent=13}
Customer{id=3, name='name3', consent=14}
Customer{id=4, name='name4', consent=15}
```

Result

```
Customer{id=10, name='name1', consent=12}
Customer{id=12, name='name3', consent=14}
Customer{id=2, name='name2', consent=13}
Customer{id=4, name='name4', consent=15}
```

Comment: The environment of above `main()` seems to be missing (as well as the end of `main()` itself).

Comment: Please review the suggested edit and try to unmistakably describe, in the introduction, what is to be the result. Which should be easier to recognise in the code if "the business logic" wasn't all lumped into `main()`.

Comment: Why are the customer IDs different in the local and remote data? Is "local" a network client and "remote" a network server? Why are the consent IDs different between local and remote data? In all four cases (local/remote, ID/consent) what are the uniqueness guarantees? What does "consent" actually represent - a customer consenting to service terms?

Answer (score 1):

I find the current algorithm of "adding and removing" to be a streamed implementation of non-functional thinking. Rather than adding and removing, I encourage you to think in terms of joining (akin to SQL outer-joining) and filtration, which are more functional concepts. In this interpretation, your "local" collection is on the left-hand side of a left outer join, and your "remote" collection is on the right. This reduces the number of iterations from your six down to two, and produces the same output:

**Customer.java**

```
package com.stackexchange.ConsentExample;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public record Customer(
    Long id,
    String name,
    Integer consent
) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
            "Customer{id=%d, name='%s', consent=%d}",
            id, name, consent);
    }

    public static Stream<Customer> join(
        Collection<Customer> locals,
        Collection<Customer> remotes
    ) {
        /* Take local consent if there is no matching remote consent.
           Take remote consent if there is a match. */
        Map<Integer, Customer> remoteByConsent =
            remotes.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Customer::consent, Function.identity()
            ));

        return locals.stream()
            .map(local ->
                remoteByConsent.getOrDefault(local.consent, local)
            );
    }
}
```

**JoinTest.java**

```
import com.stackexchange.ConsentExample.Customer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JoinTest {
    @Test
    public void testJoin() {
        final List<Customer>
        remotes = List.of(
            new Customer(10L, "name1", 12),
            new Customer(11L, "name2", 11),
            new Customer(12L, "name3", 14),
            new Customer(13L, "name4", 16)
        ),
        locals = List.of(
            new Customer(1L, "name1", 12),
            new Customer(2L, "name2", 13),
            new Customer(3L, "name3", 14),
            new Customer(4L, "name4", 15)
        );
        Map<Long, Customer> result =
            Customer.join(locals, remotes)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Customer::id, Function.identity()
            ));

        assertEquals(4, result.size());

        assertEquals("name1", result.get(10L).name());
        assertEquals(12, result.get(10L).consent());
        assertEquals("name2", result.get(2L).name());
        assertEquals(13, result.get(2L).consent());
        assertEquals("name3", result.get(12L).name());
        assertEquals(14, result.get(12L).consent());
        assertEquals("name4", result.get(4L).name());
        assertEquals(15, result.get(4L).consent());
    }
}
```